# How to create a jhipster application with different user role?

Tags: jhipster

I want to create a jhipster application with different user role ( a client, 
seller ...) but I don't know how since a jhipster generate automatically a list of users(admin, user)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create new Role with some rules, you must:
**1.** Add this role to 
**src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorities.csv**
like this:

```
NAME_OF_YOUR_ROLE
```

**2.** Connect this role with some user to

**src/main/resources/config/liquibase/users_authorities.csv**
like this:

```
5;NAME_OF_YOUR_ROLE
```

where 5 - is number of user in **users.csv**

**3.** Add to **AuthoritiesConstants.java**
public static final String NAME_OF_YOUR_ROLE = "NAME_OF_YOUR_ROLE";

Then you can work with your role in Spring Security or in AngularJs

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I didn't understand you what do you mean by "work with your role in Spring Security or in AngularJs" ?? I tried this method but the problem is that the new role  is not added to my database I don't know why.,

Comment: check new role in tables please jhi_authority and jhi_user_authority. If this role not added - try to use: liquibase:clearCheckSums and liquibase:update and then rebuild your application

Comment: Thank you for your help I solved the problem , Can you explain to me how to configure my role so that I  want to allow different angular-views my different users .

Comment: first you must add your role in security.AuthorityConstants.java, like this: public static final String YOUR_ROLE = "YOUR_ROLE"; and then you must add access for this role to BE method. User this: @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(T(app.security.AuthoritiesConstants).YOUR_ROLE)") or add access in config.SecurityConfiguration.java like this: .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/sampleMethod").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.YOUR_ROLE).

Comment: After that you will have access to method by user with new role. And add in AngularJs access: webapp.scripts. and your page - find .js and change or add: data: {
                    roles: ['YOUR_ROLE'],
                    pageTitle: 'sample.title'
                },

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really very helpful.But actually after creating and dealing with my roles I'm blocked in how to let my user access only to the entities that he created, I'm trying to add a 'created_by' attribute to my entity but I still have know how, so please could you help me  if  you have any idea about it ... thanks in advance